# UNIX :: Padding for files containing string and multipleNumber

Tags: bash

I have many files not having consistent filenames.

For example

```
IMG_20200823_1.jpg
IMG_20200823_10.jpg
IMG_20200823_12.jpg
IMG_20200823_9.jpg
```

I would like to rename all of them and ensure they all follow same naming convention

```
IMG_20200823_0001.jpg
IMG_20200823_0010.jpg
IMG_20200823_0012.jpg
IMG_20200823_0009.jpg
```

Found out it's possible to change for file having only a number using below

```
printf "%04d\n"
```

However am not able to do with my files considering they mix string + "_" + different numbers.

Could anyone help me ?
Thanks !

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html can do this, I think

Comment: I don't understand the naming convention, what would the filenames be after renaming? Which current name maps to what new name?

Answer (score 2):

With Bash regular expressions:

```sh
re='(IMG_[[:digit:]]+)_([[:digit:]]+)'

for f in *.jpg; do
    [[ $f =~ $re ]]
    mv "$f" "$(printf '%s_%04d.jpg' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}")"
done
```

where [`BASH_REMATCH`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-BASH_005fREMATCH) is an array containing the capture groups of the regular expression. At index 0 is the whole match; index 1 contains `IMG_` and the first group of digits; index 2 contains the second group of digits. The `printf` command is used to format the second group with zero padding, four digits wide.

Comment: Would it be possible to explain a bit what above does?
Not clear why BASH_REMATCH returns   IMG_20200823 (coz it's first part matching RegExp (until :digit: ?)

Comment: @FranckDeny I've added a bit of explanation.

Answer (score 2):

With Perl's standalone `rename` or `prename` command:

```
rename -n 's/(\d+)(\.jpg$)/sprintf("%04d%s",$1,$2)/e' *.jpg
```

Output:

```
rename(IMG_20200823_10.jpg, IMG_20200823_0010.jpg)
rename(IMG_20200823_12.jpg, IMG_20200823_0012.jpg)
rename(IMG_20200823_1.jpg, IMG_20200823_0001.jpg)
rename(IMG_20200823_9.jpg, IMG_20200823_0009.jpg)
```

if everything looks fine, remove `-n`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex to extract the relevant sub-strings from the input and then pad it...

1. For each file.
2. Extract the prefix, number and suffix from the filename.
3. Pad the number with zeros.
4. Create the new filename.
5. Move files

The following code for bash:

```
echo 'IMG_20200823_1.jpg
IMG_20200823_10.jpg
IMG_20200823_12.jpg
IMG_20200823_9.jpg' | 
while IFS= read -r file; do  # foreach file
    # Use GNU sed to extract parts on separate lines
    tmp=$(<<<"$file" sed 's/\(.*_\)\([0-9]*\)\(\..*\)/\1\n\2\n\3\n/')
    # Read the separate parts separated by newlines
    {
       IFS= read -r prefix
       IFS= read -r number
       IFS= read -r suffix
    } <<<"$tmp"
    # create new filename
    newfilename="$prefix$(printf "%04d" "$number")$suffix"
    # move the files
    echo mv "$file" "$newfilename"
done
```

outputs:

```
mv IMG_20200823_1.jpg IMG_20200823_0001.jpg
mv IMG_20200823_10.jpg IMG_20200823_0010.jpg
mv IMG_20200823_12.jpg IMG_20200823_0012.jpg
mv IMG_20200823_9.jpg IMG_20200823_0009.jpg
```

Comment: Amazing ! Thanks a lot !
Small tip i discovered lately - adding 
```
echo mv "$file" "$newfilename" | bash 
```
 allows to execute directly :D

Comment: `echo mv "$file" "$newfilename" | bash`... just remove the echo...

Answer (score 0):

Being puzzled by your hint at printf...

Current folder content:

```
$ ls -1 IMG_*
IMG_20200823_1.jpg
IMG_20200823_21.jpg
```

Surely is not a good solution but with printf and sed we can do that:

```
$ printf "mv %3s_%8s_%d.%3s %3s_%8s_%04d.%3s\n" $(ls -1 IMG_* IMG_* | sed 's/_/ /g; s/\./ /')
mv IMG_20200823_1.jpg IMG_20200823_0001.jpg
mv IMG_20200823_21.jpg IMG_20200823_0021.jpg
```