# Infile change padding of items

Tags: bash

Am currently parsing some websites to improve my Unix Bash skills.
Have extracted one file with following format

```
la-que-no-podia-capitulo-1
la-que-no-podia-capitulo-25
la-que-no-podia-capitulo-30
```

And would like to arrive at this step

```
la-que-no-podia-capitulo-001
la-que-no-podia-capitulo-025
la-que-no-podia-capitulo-030
```

Anyone can help me?
I've tried different approaches:

1. **Bash RegExp**

   ```
   x='a-que-no-me-dejas-capitulo-10'
   re='((([[:alpha:]]+(-))+)[[:digit:]]+)'
   if [[ $x =~ $re ]]
   then
       echo The regex matches!
       echo ${BASH_REMATCH[*]}
   fi
   ```

   (to leverage https://stackoverflow.com/a/63551084/10906045)

   But it doesn't split the last number unfortunately.
2. **AWK**

   ```
   awk -F'-' '{ printf "%04d: \n", $NF }' output_downloads >output_downloads2
   head output_downloads2

   0001: 
   0002: 
   0003: 
   0004: 
   0050:
   ```

   I can't extract first part.

Comment: `echo "la-que-no-podia-capitulo-30" | awk '-F-' -v OFS="-" '{end=$NF; $NF=""; printf("%s%03d\n", $0, end)}'`

Comment: Thanks a lot shellter !

Answer (score 5):

With awk

```sh
awk '{ match($0, /(.*-)([[:digit:]]+)$/, m); printf("%s%03d\n", m[1], m[2])}' inputfile
```

Here is the actual awk script:

```
{
  # Regex match whole line with 2 capture groups
  match($0, /(.*-)([[:digit:]]+)$/, m)

  # Format print both captured groups
  printf("%s%03d\n", m[1], m[2])
}
```

With Bash ERE:

```sh
while IFS= read -r || [[ $REPLY ]]; do
 # Regex match whole line with 2 capture groups
 [[ $REPLY =~ (.*-)([[:digit:]]+)$ ]] || :

 # Format print both captured groups
 printf '%s%03d\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
done <inputfile
```

Or with POSIX shells:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

while IFS= read -r line || [ "$line" ]; do
  IFS=-
  # Split line on dashes and fills the arguments array
  # shellcheck disable=SC2086 # Intended word splitting
  set -- $line
  # Format print arguments followed by dash except last one
  while [ $# -gt 1 ]; do
    printf '%s-' "$1"
    shift
  done
  # Format print last argument as 0-padded, 3 digits integer and newline
  printf '%03d\n' "$1"
done <inputfile
```